# How can I use the aggregate function in reactable to display a value associated with the min or max of another column?

Tags: javascript, r

I am using the `reactable` package to produce a grouped table.  When you define a grouping variable, the display is collapsed, looking like:

[image]

The above table was produced using:

```
library(reactable)

df<-data.frame(Type=c("Online","Online","Online","RL","RL","RL"),
               DaysBeforeBirthdayParty=c(9,8,7,9,8,7),
               Friends_2018=c(1,2,3,4,5,4),
               Friends_2019=c(10,15,13,19,20,21))

reactable(df,
          groupBy = "Type")
```

Several options for display of aggregation without expansion of the groups are provided here: https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/examples.html

I was originally going to use the built-in maximum function, but my data is time-related, and the most recent record isn't always the record with the maximum value in the "Friends" columns.

A custom-defined aggregation seems like the tool needed, and the author of the linked article offers the example:

```
colDef(
  aggregate = JS("
    function(values, rows) {
      // input:
      //  - values: an array of all values in the group
      //  - rows: an array of row info objects for all rows in the group
      //
      // output:
      //  - an aggregated value, e.g. a comma-separated list
      return values.join(', ')
    }
  ")
)
```

Javascript is completely unknown to me, but in searching for answers purely using queries related to Javascript and returning a value based on the minimum or maximum of a separate column, syntax didn't seem to be anything like the example here.

I'm hoping to change the function above so that it returns the value from one column (for instance Friends_2018) associated with the minimum value in another column (DaysBeforeBirthday).

The desired result would look like (when collapsed):
[image]
and, when expanded:

[image]

The values for Friends_2018 and Friends_2019 that display when collapsed should be those associated with the minimum value of DaysBeforeBirthdayParty.

My most successful attempt at this is:

```
library(reactable)

df<-data.frame(Type=c("Online","Online","Online","RL","RL","RL"),
               DaysBeforeBirthdayParty=c(9,8,7,9,8,7),
               Friends_2018=c(1,2,3,4,5,4),
               Friends_2019=c(10,15,13,19,20,21))

###sorting the data so that my row reference in the javascript
###chooses the value I want


df2<-df[order(df$DaysBeforeBirthdayParty),]

reactable(df2,
          groupBy = "Type",
          
          columns = list(
            Friends_2018 = 
          
          colDef(
            aggregate = JS("
                           function(values, rows) {
                           // input:
                           //  - values: an array of all values in the group
                           //  - rows: an array of row info objects for all rows in the group
                           //
                           // output:
                           //  - an aggregated value, e.g. a comma-separated list
                           return values[0]
                           }"))))
```

This requires that I pre-sort the data and just returns the first row value, though.

How might I build this to not rely on my pre-sort?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I would like to use a custom aggregate function to implement weighted mean.
But `return weighted.mean(rows$weight, values)` does not work. Obviously, as R is not JavaScript (thank god). But what does 'array of row info objects' mean? How exactly do I access this row info and how do I implement the function?

Comment: OK I found out how to do it. Unfortunately, I do not quite understand what you want to do so I am at a loss how to help. Please describe the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

you should be about to sort this with the `defaultExpanded` call in your react script. then just TRUE or FALSE. See below:

```
reactable(Visual_Test,
          searchable = TRUE,
          defaultSorted = "Overall",
          defaultSortOrder = "desc",
          groupBy = "Division",
          defaultExpanded = TRUE)
```